# Possible to view method / function docs in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide, documentation

NetBeans 6.5 with Python support provides the docstring documentation for a function/method in a popup when auto-completing, but is there another way to view docstrings?

Perhaps achieved by mousing over a function/method name, or clicking somewhere?

The best I can seem to do is "Go to source" in the right-click menu.

Comment: Hmm... I'd be interested to know how to do the same in PHP.  In Netbeans 6.7 Beta, holding Ctrl + hovering does display a popup, but it just gives the type and source file, not the docstring documentation you get from autocompletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the following answer from Tor Norbye at Sun:

> Hold the ctrl key (or Cmd on Mac) and then hover.
>
> Also, Ctrl-Shift-Space (e.g. code completion + shift) will display -just- the completion doc (which means it doesn't just look at the prefix of the caret, but the whole identifier and left hand side type if it can resolve it, to compute one specific match rather than many).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this keyboard shortcut on Mac. Shift + Meta + Backslash

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to the function **`Show Documentation Popup`** in **Netbeans**

Try

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>** or

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>BACK_SLASH</kbd>**

related: [How to see Javadoc documentation on mouse hover in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517266/how-to-see-javadoc-documentation-on-mouse-hover-in-netbeans)