# Possible to view method/function docs in NetBeans for PHP?

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

I am wondering if its possible to have Netbeans display PHP Documentation for functions/methods/classes when you hover the mouse over a piece of code. I know it shows up documentation as a part of code completion but I don't want to have to start typing out the name of a function which is already included within the source just to read some information on it.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463806/possible-to-view-method-function-docs-in-netbeans-python-plugin) but that covered Python and the solution given in that question of holding down Ctrl while hovering just shows a string like "Method: functionName (fileName.php) where as I would like to get the full documentation you get when you start typing out for example "MyClass::someStaticFuncti" with auto complete.

I am currently using Netbeans IDE 6.7.1 and tried this with custom classes/methods with PHPDoc and also builtin PHP functions.

Comment: The answer from @ddekany should be marked as correct, as NetBeans 7.0 provides OOTB support for this functionality in the manner described in ddekany's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the 6.7.1 version of netbeans its not possible. The only thing possible is to CTRL+Click that will take you to the declaration place and you can see the docs.
I know its not elegant but its the only thing i know possible

Comment: I don't suppose you know when / if this might be getting added?

Comment: there is nothing on the official website, i think they have a bugtracker .. so you could add a feature request and get an oficial answer

Comment: This answer is out of date, new versions of NetBeans have this feature.

Comment: Might be out-of-date, but he specifies the version for which the answer is correct. +1

Answer (score 18):

In NetBeans 7.0 there are two ways of this:

- Hold down Ctrl and hover the mouse over the method name (yes, it works for PHP now). This will not work if the line has an error, however.
- Move the cursor on the method name, and press Ctrl + **Shift** + Space

Comment: For Mac users, all references to Ctrl in this answer should be Cmd instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Netbeans 10.1 on Ubuntu 16.04**

For me the Ctrl + hover displays a non-resizable popup too small without scrollbars, so most of the long PHPDocs are out of sight.

Using Ctrl + Shift + Space *before* the symbol name as in @ddekany answer displays a list of symbols (not the one after the cursor) with their related PHPDoc underneath.

But positioning the cursor *in the middle* or *after* the symbol (method) and typing Ctrl + Space, displays a list of alternative signatures for *that* method and their PHPDoc in a pop-up with scrollbars and the options of opening the content in the external browser or navigating to the code.

Exactly what I needed.