# How to see Javadoc documentation on mouse hover in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

Is it possible, when you mouse hover on method/class so you can see Javadoc in NetBeans 7?

I want similar to Eclipse, when you just mouse hover on `String` and you can read Java API documentation about it.

Maybe there is some hot key for that...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can view the javadoc in Netbeans by clicking on the method and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>
 (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> on Mac) You can also see the various shortkeys in the help menu>keyboard shortcuts card.

**UPDATE:**

You can instead open a "javadoc" window from the menu **Window>IDE Tools>Javadoc Documentation**. This will show the javadoc in a window near the output window for that method when you click on the method or object

Comment: Is there anyway to automate this for a hover?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but instead you can open a "javadoc" window from the menu Window>other>javadoc
This will show the javadoc for that method when you click on the method or object.

Comment: @Rakesh From 8.0 it is Windows/IDE tools/javadoc. BUT! It shows the javadoc for the function you are in, not for the variable or field you are hovering over.

Comment: The answer is totally wrong now. Neither this shortcut works, nor the appropriate shortcut (ctrl+space) is present in the shortcut table. Checked for 8.0 version.

Comment: The answer was posted 3 years ago! If the shortcuts have changed in newer versions then please take a look at the "keyboard shourtcuts card" in the menu `help>keyboard shortcuts card` in your netbeans IDE.

Comment: For the NetBeans IDE **8.0.2** the above shortcut (*Ctrl+Shift+Space*) still **works**, although is not mentioned in the "Keyboard Shortcuts Card".

Comment: For the NetBeans IDE `8.2` the above shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+Space) works, and it is not mentioned in the "Keyboard Shortcuts Card". There also is another shortcut, (Ctrl+Shift+Back_Slash).

Comment: How do I see values of compile time constants? When I am not in debug mode, I thought I can hover mouse over constant (final) and look at the value. But not value is not displayed. Looked at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95691 and the issue is close to this problem. But don't this this is fixed in 8.2 release.

Answer (score 39):

I know that in netbeans 8.0 you can hold down the ctrl button and hover over the class or method, etc. and the javadoc window would appear.

Comment: In Netbeans it is even better and carefully than on Adroid Studio as on-hover docs drain cpu resources all the time.

Answer (score 19):

Javadoc won't show up with just a mouse hover, but you can click on a word (method/class/field/variable/whatever name) and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. Javadoc should show up.

Answer (score 9):

You can even open Javadoc window and you can see the javadoc in that. I prefer this way

`Window` >> `Other` >> `javadoc`.

Now you can see both your code and respective javadoc.

### Update for Netbeans 8:

`Window` >> `IDE Tools` >> `Javadoc Documentation`

Comment: Its a workaround that 1) consumes valuable real estate and 2) is not as convenient as a mouse hover feature. This should be a netbeans feature request

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook I disagree. It doesn't always consume real estate. Here's an image of NetBeans with open javadoc: http://i.imgur.com/f43m2nx.png and here is the same with closed javadoc: http://i.imgur.com/xRWx0bf.png. As you can see, you can minimize it anytime, and just click on anything that you want help with, and it's there. I mean, pressing F1 would be slower.