# Is there a way to show hover JavaDoc help using the keyboard?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard, javadoc

Eclipse shows JavaDoc help in a tooltip window when I hover with the mouse over a symbol. This is great, but it would be better if I could pop up this tooltip from the keyboard when the cursor is on the symbol. Is there a shortcut which does this?

I found <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> which opens external JavaDoc and I do not want that. I'd like to pop up the same tooltip with the keyboard which is shown on mouse hover.

Edit: Thanks, that was quick. :) I accepted the quickest answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try pressing only <kbd>F2</kbd> when cursor is on that word. It will open the same popup dialog as you get when you hover on it.

Answer (score 4):

Move the cursor on a method/class/variable and press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: LOL, I blame the office service and the line. Btw, congrats on beating me.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans 7.3 the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>
See the original answer at:
[How to see Javadoc documentation on mouse hover in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517266/how-to-see-javadoc-documentation-on-mouse-hover-in-netbeans/6517665#6517665)